# Tray icon support in Elementary 6 Odin & Single click in file manager

Tags: release-odin

I will ask 2 questions this time.
**First**
There are tons of questions here about tray icons in elementary but none of them work in my fresh Elementary 6.
One of them was like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yunnxx/elementary
sudo apt update
sudo apt install indicator-application wingpanel-indicator-ayatana
```

But it didn't work. I had error like this:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies: wingpanel-indicator-ayatana : Depends: libwingpanel-2.0-0 but it is not installable E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.` 
Then tried [Namarupa](https://github.com/donadigo/wingpanel-indicator-namarupa) but it didn't work too.

How can I fix it on Elementary 6?

**Second**
I don't like double-click in file manager of pantheon. In Elementary 5(Settings>Tweaks),there was a option for it but in Elementary 6 I couldn't find it.
How can I enable single-click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it this way...

**1º Install dependencies:**
$ sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-dev libgranite-dev libindicator3-dev libwingpanel-dev indicator-application

**2º Download:**
$ wget -c https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/raw/master/com.github.lafydev.wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.8_odin.deb

**3º Install:**
$ sudo dpkg -i ./com.github.lafydev.wingpanel*.deb

**4º Edit file:**
edit file 'indicator-application.desktop' and then add "Pantheon;" in "OnlyShowIn=Unity;GNOME;"

$ sudo nano /etc/xdg/autostart/indicator-application.desktop

**5º Reboot.**

**Source:**
https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana

About the **single-click** i don't know how to fix this :/ the pantheon-tweaks don't show this option...

Comment: I couldn't find anything about single click in Elementary Odin too but I "solved" it by using nautilus since pantheon is based on gnome. Thanks for your great answer. It really worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is just and only update, just change link with newer version:

2º Download:

```
wget -c https://github.com/Lafydev/wingpanel-indicator-ayatana/raw/master/com.github.lafydev.wingpanel-indicator-ayatana_2.0.8_odin.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I changed Elementary now :D

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, elementaryOS 7 (Horus) adds an option in Files to switch between single- and double-click modes. Just right-click in the Files window and there is a new option: "Double-click to Navigate"